# Computing Essential Matrix from Fundamental Matrix

Tags: computer-vision

I have calibrated my cameras using OpenCV. 
I used `cv.stereoCalibrate` to get the E, and F matrices. I wanted to do a sanity check to see if the E matrix obtained is the same from what is manually computed, but I did not get the same results.

I am using `E = np.dot(np.dot(K2.T, F), K1)`

K2 is the Second (Right) Camera Matrix & K1 is the First (Left) Camera Matrix.

The values obtained from `cv.stereoCalibrate` are -

```
K1 = array([[934.06230207,   0.        , 959.99754346],
           [  0.        , 933.44096222, 539.98442119],
           [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]])
```

```
K2 = array([[935.93262747,   0.        , 960.00167839],
            [  0.        , 936.1379955 , 539.98789096],
            [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]])
```

```
E = array([[-4.27815162e-05, -6.90641692e-02,  3.35371623e-02],
          [ 5.78660464e-02,  1.37740833e-02,  1.20282641e+01],
          [-3.54642135e-02, -1.20281991e+01,  1.37524047e-02]])
```

```
F = array([[-1.45461342e-09, -2.34981243e-06,  2.33536635e-03],
           [ 1.96707058e-06,  4.68541244e-07,  3.79780838e-01],
           [-2.18936224e-03, -3.81020843e-01,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

If I compute `E = np.dot(np.dot(K2.T, F), K1)`
I get

```
E = array([[-1.27165124e-03, -2.05288509e+00,  9.96869161e-01],
          [ 1.72002857e+00,  4.09425185e-01,  3.57531907e+02],
           [-1.05414944e+00, -3.57529974e+02,  4.08780803e-01]])
```

This is not equal to the E I got from OpenCV.
enter code here

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, PyWalker2797. What results are you getting? Where are `K2` and `K1` coming from? Why are they different?

Comment: I updated my question with some more information. K2 and K1 are the camera matrices of the second and first camera respectively.

Comment: Error in E can be due to noise in camera intrinsic parameters. This can be solved by reconstructing the singular values of E. If you haven't solved this problem yet , let me know, I will answer that here!

Comment: I did not, but please feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling the function? The [documentation says](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#double%20stereoCalibrate(InputArrayOfArrays%20objectPoints,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints1,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints2,%20InputOutputArray%20cameraMatrix1,%20InputOutputArray%20distCoeffs1,%20InputOutputArray%20cameraMatrix2,%20InputOutputArray%20distCoeffs2,%20Size%20imageSize,%20OutputArray%20R,%20OutputArray%20T,%20OutputArray%20E,%20OutputArray%20F,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20flags)):

> And the function can also compute the fundamental matrix F:
>
> ```
> F = cameraMatrix2^{-T} E cameraMatrix1^{-1}
> ```

And checking this doesn't give a correct/matching number either, so I'm wondering if maybe you've left an argument out and it's causing and off-by-one error that's failing to send the right parameter to the correct output.

Comment: I will check but I am passing all the parameters correctly and passing `None` for parameters that don't need values so that the order does not get messed up